# Two video tag appears when I restart the video with amazon chime js

Tags: video, amazon-chime

When I use stopLocalVideoTile() for video off. It is working. But when I want start again the video that time (using .startLocalVideoTile() ) that time video is start properly for that user but other attendees can see 2 window that user ( one is for video off and one is for video on).
Please help me on that.

I attached a screenshot for that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sbth.png)

I want to add video on off  facility  in a meeting using amazon chime js.

I add stopLocalVideoTile for video off and startLocalVideoTile for video restart.
I want in every screen of user and attendees can see single video for one user after using video on foo function.